# Irregular shape textbox in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've been trying to create slides in Powerpoint whose text can wrap as in a textbox container of irregular shape, such as a polygon with a weird cut-out, or a non-straightforward curve, like this for example:
[image]

In Powerpoint 2021, inserting a shape of whichever kind, and typing in it, doesn't seem to have an effect on the wrapping of the text. The only workaround I found is simply to add line breaks manually until the "envelope" of the text has the desired shape.

Any Powerpoint-native solutions for this challenge (or creative hacks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's just using spacebars and new lines as you do.

If the shape isn't really curvy, I just use several text boxes and distribute the text there.

There is a more complicated way shown [here](https://www.presentation-process.com/powerpoint-wrap-text-around-picture.html), *option 3*. It utilizes MS Word as it has the text wrapping function.

So, basically you:

1. Make a transparent image or custom shape in MS Word
2. Add some text
3. Choose image wrapping as tight
4. Position your image
5. Save the Word file
6. Import it to Powerpoint as an object.

This is how the resulting PowerPoint looks:
[image]

Object can be resized and it can be edited in Powerpoint with double-click.
Yet I should tell you it's a pain. Might be a good solution for certain cases, but in your case using line breaks is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks! Manual solutions are certainly actually time-wise smarter to employ in some situations than insisting to spend time on coming up with an elegant automated solution!